# UTF-8 Encoding size

Tags: unicode, utf-8

what unicode characters fit in 1, 2, 4 bytes? Can someone point me to complete character chart?

Comment: Read this first: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: A complete chart? That's going to be a HUGE one. See this for a printed version of the Basic Multilingual Plane (there are 16 more): http://shop.designinmainz.de/en/Poster/decodeunicode-Basic-Multilingual-Plane-BMP-Map See DecodeUnicode for a wiki-like representation of Unicode characters: http://www.decodeunicode.org/en

Comment: You could also read about Universal Codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_code_%28data_compression%29

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many characters can UTF-8 encode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229156/how-many-characters-can-utf-8-encode)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Characters are encoded according to their position in the range. You can actually find the algorithm on the Wikipedia page for UTF8 - you can implement it very quickly
[Wikipedia UTF8 Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

- U+0000 to U+007F are (correctly) encoded with one byte
- U+0080 to U+07FF are encoded with 2 bytes
- U+0800 to U+FFFF are encoded with 3 bytes
- U+010000 to U+10FFFF are encoded with 4 bytes

Answer (score 6):

The wikipedia article on [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8) has a good enough description of the encoding:

- 1 byte = code points 0x000000 to 0x00007F (inclusive)
- 2 bytes = code points 0x000080 to 0x0007FF
- 3 bytes = code points 0x000800 to 0x00FFFF
- 4 bytes = code points 0x010000 to 0x10FFFF

The charts can be downloaded directly from [unicode.org](http://www.unicode.org/charts/). It's a set of about 150 PDF files, because a single chart would be huge (maybe 30 MiB).

Also be aware that Unicode (compared to something like ASCII) is much more complex to process - there's things like right-to-left text, byte order marks, code points that can be combined ("composed") to create a single character and different ways of representing the exact same string (and a process to convert strings into a canonical form suitable for comparison), a lot more white-space characters, etc. I'd recommend downloading the entire Unicode specification and reading most of it if you're planning to do more than "not much".

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 compromises of 1 to a limit of 6 bytes, although the current amount of code points is covered with just 4 bytes. UTF-8 uses the first byte to determine how long (in bytes) the character is - see the various links to the Wiki page:

[UTF-8 Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Single byte UTF-8 is effectively ASCII - UTF-8 was designed to be compatible with it, which is why it's more prevalent than UTF-16, for example.

---

Edit: Apparently, it was agreed the UTF-8's code points would not exceed 21 bits (4 byte sequences) - but it has the technical capability to handle up to 31 bits (6 byte UTF-8).

Comment: UTF-8 is limited to 4 bytes. Unicode code points are limited to U+1FFFFF (21 bits), and UTF-8 encoding is canonical (must choose shortest). Therefore, you can never end up with a 5 byte UTF-8 sequence. Either it would decode to a character past U+1FFFFF, or it would not be canonical.

Comment: UTF-8's current character set only uses 4 bytes, but it was designed for code points up to 31 bits - resulting in a 6 byte sequence.

Comment: *6-byte characters*? [shudder]

Comment: You're correct, though Wiki has so much dumby history that I'm angry to scroll and read through it xd

Comment: I was looking for an answer mentioning the 6 bytes maximum like this, but I was also wanting to know the max code point. I thought it'd be U+FFFFFF, like ECMAScript 4.