# How many characters can UTF-8 encode?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

If UTF-8 is 8 bits, does it not mean that there can be only maximum of 256 different characters?

The first 128 code points are the same as in ASCII. But it says UTF-8 can support up to million of characters?

How does this work?

Comment: In the UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 encodings of Unicode, the number is the number of bits in its _code units_, one or more of which encode a Unicode codepoint.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

UTF-8 does not use one byte all the time, it's 1 to 4 bytes.

> The first 128 characters (US-ASCII) need one byte.
>
> The next 1,920 characters need two bytes to encode. This covers the remainder of almost all Latin alphabets, and also Greek, Cyrillic, Coptic, Armenian, Hebrew, Arabic, Syriac and Tāna alphabets, as well as Combining Diacritical Marks.
>
> Three bytes are needed for characters in the rest of the Basic Multilingual Plane, which contains virtually all characters in common use[12] including most Chinese, Japanese and Korean [CJK] characters.
>
> Four bytes are needed for characters in the other planes of Unicode, which include less common CJK characters, various historic scripts, mathematical symbols, and emoji (pictographic symbols).

source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: hi @zwippie i new to this. There is something i dont get it.! BMP uses 2 bytes you say is 3? am i wrong?

Comment: @chiperortiz, BMP is indeed 16 bits, so it can be encoded as UTF-16 with constant length per character (UTF-16 also supports going beyond 16 bits, but it's a difficult practice, and many implementations don't support it).
However, for UTF-8, you also need to encode how long it will be, so you lose some bits. Which is why you need 3 bytes to encode the complete BMP.
This may seem as wasteful, but remember that UTF-16 always uses 2 bytes, but UTF-8 uses one byte per character for most latin-based language characters. Making it twice as compact.

Comment: The main thrust of the OP's question is related to why it is called UTF-**8** -- this doesn't really answer that.

Comment: @sanderd17 the diff between utf8 and 16 is that utf-8 can use as minimum 1 byte (sufficient for latin) whereas 16 needs at least 2 bytes?

Comment: **How many characters can UTF-8 encode?**

Comment: @a55 UTF-8 can encode all the codepoints of unicode. Right now there are about 150k registered codepoints, and Unicode can support up to 1,112,064 codepoints. Characters is a much looser term, and in theory codepoints can be combined to create infinite characters. ‍‍‍ This emoji is 7 codepoints, 25 bytes, and 1 character. ‍‍ this emoji is a substring of last one. Codepoints: ["", "‍", "", "‍", "", "‍", ""]. Hex: ["1F468", "200D", "1F469", "200D", "1F467", "200D", "1F467"]

Answer (score 61):

UTF-8 uses 1-4 bytes per character: one byte for ascii characters (the first 128 unicode values are the same as ascii). But that only requires 7 bits. If the highest ("sign") bit is set, this indicates the start of a multi-byte sequence; the number of consecutive high bits set indicates the number of bytes, then a 0, and the remaining bits contribute to the value.  For the other bytes, the highest two bits will be 1 and 0 and the remaining 6 bits are for the value.

So a four byte sequence would begin with 11110... (and ... = three bits for the value) then three bytes with 6 bits each for the value, yielding a 21 bit value. 2^21 exceeds the number of unicode characters, so all of unicode can be expressed in UTF8.

Comment: @NickL.  No, I mean 3 bytes.  In that example, if the first byte of a multibyte sequence begins 1111, the first 1 indicates that it *is* the beginning of a multibyte sequence, then the number of consecutive 1's after that indicates the number of *additional* bytes in the sequence (so a first byte will begin either 110, 1110, or 11110).

Comment: Found proof for your words in RFC 3629. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629#section-3 . However, I don't understand why do I need to place "10" in the beginning of the second byte 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx ? Why not just 110xxxxx xxxxxxxx ?

Comment: Found answer in https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262227/why-does-utf-8-waste-several-bits-in-its-encoding . Just for safety reasons (in case a single byte in the middle of the stream is corrupted)

Comment: @kolobok Ah.  Sans safety you could then encode a 21-bit value in 3 bytes (3 bits indicating the length, plus 21-bits).  :D  Probably that is not so meaningful though, at least WRT Western languages.

Comment: I'm guessing that NickL asked this but what happened to the rest of the bits in that first byte if the ... represents subsequent bytes instead of bits?

Comment: @NickL "So a four byte sequence would begin with 11110... (... = three bytes for the value)"  should have read *"...= three bits"* (thanks). This is why a 4 byte utf8 character has a 21-bit value (3 + 6 + 6 + 6).

Comment: Thanks! Future readers use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)

Comment: Why everyone is writing a long wall of text, when the technical description can fit in a small paragraph like here! Thumbs up!

Answer (score 43):

## Unicode vs UTF-8

Unicode resolves code points to characters. UTF-8 is a storage mechanism for Unicode. Unicode has a spec. UTF-8 has a spec. They both have different limits. UTF-8 has a different upwards-bound.

### Unicode

Unicode is designated with ["planes."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)) Each plane carries 2<sup>16</sup> code points. There are 17 Planes in Unicode. For a total of `17 * 2^16` code points. The [first plane, plane 0 or the BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), is special in the weight of what it carries.

Rather than explain all the nuances, let me just quote the above article on planes.

> The 17 planes can accommodate 1,114,112 code points. Of these, 2,048 are surrogates, 66 are non-characters, and 137,468 are reserved for private use, leaving 974,530 for public assignment.

## UTF-8

Now let's go back to the article linked above,

> The encoding scheme used by UTF-8 was designed with a much larger limit of 2<sup>31</sup> code points (32,768 planes), and can encode 2<sup>21</sup> code points (32 planes) even if limited to 4 bytes.[3] Since Unicode limits the code points to the 17 planes that can be encoded by UTF-16, code points above 0x10FFFF are invalid in UTF-8 and UTF-32.

So you can see that you can put stuff into UTF-8 that isn't valid Unicode. Why? Because UTF-8 accommodates code points that Unicode doesn't even support.

UTF-8, even with a four byte limitation, supports 2<sup>21</sup> code points, which is far more than `17 * 2^16`

Answer (score 31):

2,164,864 “characters” can be potentially coded by UTF-8.

This number is `27 + 211 + 216 + 221`, which comes from the way the encoding works:

- 1-byte chars have 7 bits for encoding
  `0xxxxxxx` (0x00-0x7F)
- 2-byte chars have 11 bits for encoding
  `110xxxxx 10xxxxxx` (0xC0-0xDF for the first byte; 0x80-0xBF for the second)
- 3-byte chars have 16 bits for encoding
  `1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx` (0xE0-0xEF for the first byte; 0x80-0xBF for continuation bytes)
- 4-byte chars have 21 bits for encoding
  `11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx` (0xF0-0xF7 for the first byte; 0x80-0xBF for continuation bytes)

As you can see this is significantly larger than current Unicode (1,112,064 characters).

**UPDATE**

My initial calculation is wrong because it doesn't consider additional rules. See comments to this answer for more details.

Comment: Your math doesn't respect the UTF-8 rule that only the shortest code unit sequence is allowed to encode a codepoint. So, 00000001 is valid for U+0001 but  11110000 10000000 10000000 10000001 is not. Ref: [Table 3-7. Well-Formed UTF-8 Byte Sequences](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/ch03.pdf). Besides, the question is directly answered by the table: you just add up the ranges. (They are disjoint to exclude surrogates for UTF-16).

Comment: Tom - thanks for your comment! I was unaware of those restrictions. I saw [table 3-7](https://imgur.com/a/5J3nJ) and [ran the numbers](https://imgur.com/a/kmfO5) and it looks like there are 1,083,392 possible valid sequences.

Comment: This is an accurate answer. Other answers have just stopped at `2^21` and forgot the rest of the combinations possible.

Comment: Yes, theoretically there are `2^7 + 2^11 + 2^16 + 2^21` symbols but a lot of them are invalid by UTF8 rules, so in the end < 2^21. UTF8 must encode `1114112` Unicode symbols and `2^21` is enough. Though many forget that there are symbol combinations – **diacritic modifiers**, **skin tone modifiers**, **zero-width-joiner**, **flags**, etc. UTF8 symbols are 1-4 bytes, but combination of these symbols could be 6/8/20/... bytes, which can express much more "visible" symbols

Comment: @RubenReyes The input data in your excel sheet is wrong due to which your total is incorrect. I ran the numbers and there are exactly 1,112,064 valid UTF-8 byte sequences, which is precisely all the code points from U+0000 to U+10FFFF minus the surrogate halves from U+D800 to U+DFFF. Thus, there are exactly 1,114,112 - 2,048 = 1,112,064 valid UTF-8 byte sequences, or 2^16 + 2^20 - 2^11 byte sequences. The mistake in your input data is in the 2nd byte hex end column. It should be 80..BF instead of 80..9F for the 4th and the 6th row respectively.

Answer (score 30):

According to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=UTF-8&oldid=730630603#Description)* UTF-8 *should* support:

2<sup>31</sup> = 2,147,483,648 characters

However, RFC 3629 restricted the possible values, so now we're [capped at 4 bytes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-3), which gives us

2<sup>21</sup> = 2,097,152 characters

Note that a good chunk of those characters are "reserved" for custom use, which is actually pretty handy for icon-fonts.

* Wikipedia used show a table with 6 bytes -- they've since updated the article.

> **2017-07-11:** Corrected for double-counting the same code point encoded with multiple bytes

Comment: This answer is double counting the number of encodings possible.  Once you have counted all 2^7, you cannot count them again in 2^11, 2^16, etc.  The correct number of encodings possible is 2^21 (though not all are currently being used).

Comment: @Jimmy You sure I'm double counting? `0xxxxxxx` gives 7 usable bits, `110xxxxx 10xxxxxx` gives 11 more -- there's no overlap. The first byte starts with `0` in the first case, and `1` in the second case.

Comment: @mpen so what code point does `00000001` store and what does `11000000 100000001` store?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Uhh....point taken. Didn't realize there were multiple ways to encode the same code point.

Answer (score 12):

UTF-8 is a *variable length* encoding with **a minimum** of 8 bits per character.
Characters with higher code points will take up to 32 bits.

Comment: This is misleading. The longest code point you can have is [`11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629), so only 21 bits can be used for encoding the actual character.

Comment: I said code points may take up to 32 bits to be encoded, I never claimed that (by induction) you can encode 2^32 characters in 32 bit UTF-8. But that is rather moot, since you can encode *all* existing Unicode characters in UTF-8, and you *can* encode even more if you stretch UTF-8 to 48 bits (which exists but is deprecated), so I'm not sure what the misleading point is.

Answer (score 5):

Quote from Wikipedia: "UTF-8 encodes each of the 1,112,064 code points in the Unicode character set using one to four 8-bit bytes (termed "octets" in the Unicode Standard)."

Some links:

- http://www.utf-8.com/
- http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html
- http://www.icu-project.org/docs/papers/forms_of_unicode/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Unicode Standard and related information, such as their FAQ entry, [UTF-8 UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html). It’s not that smooth sailing, but it’s authoritative information, and much of what you might read about UTF-8 elsewhere is questionable.

The “8” in “UTF-8” relates to the length of *code units* in bits. Code units are entities use to encode characters, not necessarily as a simple one-to-one mapping. UTF-8 uses a variable number of code units to encode a character.

The collection of characters that can be encoded in UTF-8 is exactly the same as for UTF-16 or UTF-32, namely all Unicode characters. They all encode the entire Unicode coding space, which even includes noncharacters and unassigned code points.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with mpen on the current maximum UTF-8 codes (2,164,864) (listed below, I couldn't comment on his), he is off by 2 levels if you remove the 2 major restrictions of UTF-8: only 4 bytes limit and codes 254 and 255 can not be used (he only removed the 4 byte limit).

Starting code 254 follows the basic arrangement of starting bits (multi-bit flag set to 1, a count of 6 1's, and terminal 0, no spare bits) giving you 6 additional bytes to work with (6 10xxxxxx groups, an additional 2^36 codes).

Starting code 255 doesn't exactly follow the basic setup, no terminal 0 but all bits are used, giving you 7 additional bytes (multi-bit flag set to 1, a count of 7 1's, and no terminal 0 because all bits are used; 7 10xxxxxx groups, an additional 2^42 codes).

Adding these in gives a final maximum presentable character set of 4,468,982,745,216.  This is more than all characters in current use, old or dead languages, and any believed lost languages.  Angelic or Celestial script anyone?

Also there are single byte codes that are overlooked/ignored in the UTF-8 standard in addition to 254 and 255: 128-191, and a few others.  Some are used locally by the keyboard, example code 128 is usually a deleting backspace.  The other starting codes (and associated ranges) are invalid for one or more reasons (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Invalid_byte_sequences).

Answer (score -2):

Unicode is firmly married to UTF-8. Unicode specifically supports 2^21 code points (2,097,152 characters) which is exactly the same number of code points supported by UTF-8. Both systems reserve the same 'dead' space and restricted zones for code points etc. [...as of June 2018 the most recent version, Unicode 11.0, contains a repertoire of 137,439 characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)

**From the unicode standard.** [Unicode FAQ](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)

> The Unicode Standard encodes characters in the range U+0000..U+10FFFF,
>   which amounts to a 21-bit code space.

**From the UTF-8 Wikipedia page.** [UTF-8 Description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description)

> Since the restriction of the Unicode code-space to 21-bit values in
>   2003, UTF-8 is defined to encode code points in one to four bytes, ...

Comment: 21 bits is rounded up. Unicode supports 1,114,112 codepoints (U+0000 to U+10FFFF) like it says. (Sometimes described as 17 planes of 65536.)

Comment: @TomBlodget, You are correct. the most relevant takeaway from this discussion is that UTF-8 can encode all the currently defined points in the Unicode standard and will likely be able to so for quite some time to come.