# BSON how does a binary protocol work'? how do I read a (pseudo-)Backus-Naur-Form?

Tags: mongodb, bson

I'm reading MongoDB specs and it uses data format [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification)

Looking at the doc, I'd like to understand how the example BSON at the bottom of their page is encoded

```
{"hello": "world"}  →   "\x16\x00\x00\x00\x02hello\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00world\x00\x00"

{"BSON": ["awesome", 5.05, 1986]}   →   "\x31\x00\x00\x00\x04BSON\x00\x26\x00 
 \x00\x00\x020\x00\x08\x00\x00 
 \x00awesome\x00\x011\x00\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33\x33
 \x14\x40\x102\x00\xc2\x07\x00\x00 
 \x00\x00"
```

Comment: What do you mean, "how does it work"? It's a binary protocol.

Comment: I mean what does each byte mean?

Comment: Knowledge of BSON data format is not necessary to use MongoDB. All drivers hide these details from you. You'll never have to write these bytes yourself. Why do you want to know this, again?

Comment: Also, the specification is right there, at the link you posted yourself.

Comment: It is of course encoded per character by using a encoding table derived from the link you gave

Comment: I know I don't have to understand it to use MongoDB. I'm just curious.

Comment: If you don't know the answer, just don't answer. Don't have to lecture me what I need to know and whatnot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is essentially 'how does a binary protocol work'? Or `how do I read a (pseudo-)Backus-Naur-Form?

You can think of it like this: Your protocol consists of format information that is used to structure the data, and the data itself. What you see in JSON as an opening bracket `{`, for example, means something like "start a new (sub-)document".

Per definition, this 'command' is implicit and simply consists of the length of everything that is to follow, then the content (an `e_list`), then a `\x00` terminator byte. So, since the document is 22 bytes long (that is 0x16 in hex), the 'command' is `\x16\x00\x00\x00`. Why the three `\x00`? Because we need an int32, i.e. a 32-bit integer so it must be padded to a full four bytes. Why `\x16\x00\x00\x00` and not `\x00\x00\x00\x16`? This is called endianess and BSON uses little-endian.

Then comes the defintion of the content, the `e_list`. An `e_list` is defined as an `element` followed by another e_list, which can be empty and then terminates. An `element` is defined as the type of the value first, then the `e_name`, followed by the actual data. So, since the *value* of `"hello"` is `"world"`, which is a string and strings are identified by a `\x02` according to the spec, the `\x02` comes next, followed by the `e_name` "hello" and a null terminator (`hello\x00`).

Now comes the actual value which is a string, which is defined as `int32 (byte*) "\x00"`, i.e. the length of the string, the actual data and a null terminator (with the length including the null terminator), so the length becomes `\x06\x00\x00\x00`, followed by the actual data `world\x00` and the `\x00` terminator for the top-level BSON document.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very clear answer. Also found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169879/can-i-get-more-explanations-for-bson?rq=1_)