# Why C11 define character constant recursively?

Tags: character, constants, c11

The character constants are defined in c11 as:
 ***Syntax**

  character-constant:

   ' c-char-sequence '

   L' c-char-sequence '

   u' c-char-sequence '

   U' c-char-sequence '

  c-char-sequence:

   c-char

   c-char-sequence c-char

  c-char:

   any member of the source character set except the single-quote ', backslash \, or new-line character

   escape-sequence*

It is defined recursively, so inside the single-quotes, there are one or more c-chars, like 'abc'.
However as I know, a character constant contains only one c-char, like 'a', doesn't it?

Comment: Characters are UTF-8 as far as I know. It can support characters beyond what ASCII can. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229156/how-many-characters-can-utf-8-encode

Comment: The Macintosh File System used four bytes constants for file types and file application creator, like `'TEXT'` for a text file, `'APPL'` for an application. File name extensions were rarely used (mostly used for programming and web publishing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> as I know, a character constant contains only one c-char, like 'a', doesn't it?

no, `'abcd'` is also a character constant. Its value is technically implementation-defined, but everywhere I've looked it was formed out of the values of the chars, in big-endian order (in that case, 0x61626364)

The C side of cppreference has a discussion of various [character constants](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant)