# Convert InputStream to String and Round Trip Using UTF8 in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, utf

Consider a following code snippet

```
byte[] b = new byte[]{ 0, 0, 0, -127 };  // possible Byte Array

// converted byte array to String using UTF-8
String s = String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Now try again to convert the string into byte array

```
b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

now when we compare it with original byte array, the value is not same on round trip

```
[0, 0, 0, -17, -65, -67]
```

Can anyone suggest how can we convert back the string to original byte array

Comment: Your byte array isn't a valid UTF-8 string.

Comment: see how many bytes is a utf-8 char.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229156/how-many-characters-can-utf-8-encode

Comment: If your InputStream contains those characters, then it's not reading from a UTF-8 source. Make sure you use the correct encoding in the first place.

Comment: I still cannot understand why you need signed values for a UTF-8 conversion

Comment: There is no InputStream here.

Comment: This is actually some maintenance project, and code was there already written in this way... which is reason for corruption of data, i am now trying to write an adaptar layer above to restore back the data

Answer (score 1):

The most stable answer is that you should go between a byte array and a hex string which is `1 byte == 2 character` between `0` and `F` in a `UTF-8` format.

Then convert back from hex to byte array  To other stack trace questions for how to go to them.

Byte to hex:
[How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java)

Hex to byte: 
[Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot understand the reason why you need a not valid UTF-8 string, I have an **explaining** solution for you (paste this code into your `TestDrive` class (a runnable class containing `static void main(String[] args) function`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] bytes1 = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, -127};
    int[] unsigned = toUnsignedInt(bytes1);
    String utf8String = toUtf8String(unsigned);
    char[] chars = utf8String.toCharArray();
    byte[] bytes2 = toBytes(chars);
    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(bytes1, bytes2));
}

private static int[] toSigned(byte[] unsigned) {
    int[] signed = new int[unsigned.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < unsigned.length; i++) {
        signed[i] = 2;
    }
    return signed;
}

private static int[] toUnsignedInt(byte[] signed) {
    int[] unsigned = new int[signed.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < signed.length; i++) {
        unsigned[i] = Byte.toUnsignedInt(signed[i]);
    }
    return unsigned;
}

private static String toUtf8String(int[] unsigned) {
    char[] chars = toChars(unsigned);
    return new String(chars);
}

private static char[] toChars(int[] unsigned) {
    char[] chars = new char[unsigned.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < unsigned.length; i++) {
        chars[i] = (char) unsigned[i];
    }
    return chars;
}

private static byte[] toBytes(char[] chars) {
    int[] unsigned = toUnsignedInt(chars);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[unsigned.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < unsigned.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = (byte) unsigned[i];
    }
    return bytes;
}

private static int[] toUnsignedInt(char[] chars) {
    int[] unsigned = new int[chars.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        unsigned[i] = (int) chars[i];
    }
    return unsigned;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The most stable answer is to leave the byte array alone and pass *it* around, and avoid the String and round-trip completely. String is not a container for binary data.