# String length data for DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I try to convert the string length of 400KB (the maximum size of a DynamoDB item) to characters.

I don't know if KB is kilobytes (in this case 400 000 characters) OR kilobits (in this case 51 200 characters).

Do you know that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely 400 KiloBytes. But DynamoDb uses `UTF-8` encoding for the strings. So if the your string is `UTF-16` encoded, it may or may not fit as one dynamodb item. Secondly the 400KB limit also includes the binary length of the attribute key names you have in the table.

[How many characters can UTF-8 encode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229156/how-many-characters-can-utf-8-encode)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-items

Comment: Just for precision If I've 400 000 characters in UTF-16 encoded I need two items, right ?